# The function stops creating agents

Tags: anylogic

Can you tell me what function to stop creating agents?

I am using CarSource and in the action there is the following code:

```
gruz1 = (int)uniform( 15, 20);
if (gruz>0 && gruz>=gruz1) {
    gruz = gruz - gruz1;
}
else {
    /*--function stops creating agents--*/
}
```

I need to stop creating agents, and the model itself continued to work.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to limit the rate to 0:

```
self.set_rate(0);
```